# Как реализовать передачу даных между программами?

Tags: c

Допустим, есть две программы. Одна просит пользователя ввести имя в массив символов, а вторая выводит имя, из своего массива символов. Как передать содержание одного массива во второй без записи и чтения файла?

Comment: Ключевое слово, как уже заметили, IPC. А дальше уж на что фантазии хватит: socket, file descriptor, DBus, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть три стандартных способа:

1. Очереди сообщений (есть два вида очередей - POSIX и System V)
2. Каналы (именованные и не именованные)
3. Разделяемая память

Ваша задача - классический пример задачи "Производитель -> потребитель". Что бы не заморачиваться с кольцевыми буферами и прочим, рекомендую использовать именованный канал.

```
man 3 mkfifof

mkfifo - make FIFOs (named pipes)
Create named pipes (FIFOs) with the given NAMEs.
```

Самый простой пример:

1. В командной строке выполняем команду mkfifo my_pipe
2. Пишем и запускаем программу потребителя, которая открывает my_pipe как обычный файл и виснет на ожидании чтения.
3. Пишем и запускаем программу поставщика, которая открывает my_pipe на запись и пишет данные туда.
4. Начинается обмен данными по каналу.

Здесь существенен порядок(!) запуска этих программ. Если первым запустить производителя, то программа свалится по попытке записи в канал, из которого никто не читает.

Comment: Можно пример самой простой поги.

Comment: Для именованного  пайпа всё очень просто - пример дописал в ответ.

Comment: А как сделать передачу данных от программы к программе, причём принимающая программа ждет ввод с клавиатуры? Без my_pipe! Передающая к примеру генерирует имена.

Comment: Не понял: **причём принимающая программа ждет ввод с клавиатуры** - это как ? Я предполагал, что **принимающая** программа ждёт ввода от **передающей**. Разве не так ?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, для таких вещей делают у одной из программ, к которой подключаться, некое API, SAPI — для того чтобы другая программа смогла получить нужное для себя.